# Calculating accuracy and cost on dev/test sets

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a rather general question about developing neural networks. It is still related to how to program a model.

When training a model, it is a common practice to calculate cost (and maybe even accuracy) periodically to be able to check the trend of the progress. The cost is maybe not calculated after every epoch but maybe every - say - 100th epoch, and saved somewhere to draw a graph of it at the end. Especially if the data set is very large, (based on what I have seen so far) this cost is then only calculated on a mini-batch rather than the entire training data set and the cost of the model is calculated by taking the average of all these training set mini_batch costs.

While training the model, I would like to calculate cost (and maybe even accuracy) periodically even on the dev and test sets, to be later able to compare trends (especially between training set and dev set) to have a better picture of how the model is working. But I read the train data from csv file(s) in a while loop as following:

```
...
...
try:
        while not coord.should_stop():
          _ , minibatch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost])

          nr_of_minibatches += 1
          cost_of_model += minibatch_cost
          cost_of_model /= nr_of_minibatches

          # Print and save the progress (cost, accuracy, etc) periodically
          if print_progress == True and nr_of_minibatches % 5 == 0:
              print ("Cost after minibatch %i: %f" % (nr_of_minibatches, cost_of_model))
              costs.append(cost_of_model)
              accuracy_train = accuracy.eval() #(feed_dict={ZL: ZL, Y_mini_batch: Y_mini_batch})
              train_accuracies.append(accuracy_train)
              print("accuracy_train = " + str(accuracy_train))
              test_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X_Y_mini_batch: Y_test})
      except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('Done training, epoch reached')
      finally:
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
...
...
```

This while loop wil be looping as long as # of epochs is not completed on train set csv file(s). And as seen above, after each 5th mini batch, I calculate the cost. I would like to add the cost/accuracy calculation even for dev and test data sets.

Question 1) From a practical point of view, I assume that dev and test set data should reside in separate csv files. Would you agree with me? If not, (if you think it is OK that all train/dev/test sets can be in the same file), how should I then implement it in tensorflow? I guess Scikit-learn has a trick for it but I assume train/dev/test data should be separate in tensorflow implementations.

Question 2) If train/dev/test data should be in separate csv files, how should the implementation look like? The given while loop above is looping through train csv files.I am a bit confused regarding how to implement it elegantly so that after each - say - 5th train epoch I re-calculate the cost/accuracy for dev/test sets as well that are in separate csv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `try/except/finally` blocks have faulty indentation. The `except` and `finally` statements should be at the same level of indentation as `try`.

As far as splitting your data, you can do things either way, it depends on your particular use case. You can keep all data in one big CSV file and have the program split the data into separate blocks for training/dev/test, or you can keep 3 separate CSV files. The only thing to be careful on is if you choose to keep all the data in one CSV file, the method by which you split the data up into train/dev/test sets should be reproducible or else you will end up training on your dev/test sets by accident if you train your model more than once.

How you split up the data is not unique to the deep learning package that you use. You can certainly use Scikit-learn's method of splitting data and then run your training with Tensorflow. There's no reason to reinvent the wheel for a Tensorflow specific data-split.

One thing I would advise against is checking the cost/accuracy on the test set during training. That defeats the purpose of the test set. You can use the dev set to fine tune the hyper-parameters in your model, but you should only ever use the test set at the very end to see what your cost/accuracy is likely to look like in the "real world". You don't want to ever over fit to your test set, that's the whole point of splitting data into 3 sets.

If you choose to keep the files separate, it means you will have a loop within your loop that goes over the separate file and calculates the cost/accuracy on the separate dev set file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I agree with your points. The indentation is just a typo.

When you say: "If you choose to keep the files separate, it means you will have a loop within your loop that goes over the separate file and calculates the cost/accuracy on the separate dev set file. "
This inner loop you are talking about.. Should it calculat the cost on the entire dev set or a part of it? You probably will say "it depends on the size of dev set" but I still wanted to ask your opinion.. :)

Comment: Usually you would just calculate it for the entire dev set unless you are running into resource problems or if it's taking too long. You can do as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very valuable.

Comment: A side question to this topic.. When calculating the cost and accuracy on dev set periodically, is it ok to create a new session just for this purpose? Or is the recommended practice to use the session in which the training is going on on the train data set? As it looks, it makes it a bit complicated to try to use the same session. But I might be mistaken too.